# Importing a checkout svn source code as java project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, import, project

I have a project whose source code is hosted in svn and I have checked out the source code already say in a folder "myfolder". The directory structure of my code is as follows:
myfolder/trunk/src/ is where my code resides. Now I create a Java project using eclipse using File -> new java project with the location to be myfolder/trunk/src/. When I do this, all the package structure gets changes and I have errors in my sources files.

It would be great if somebody can tell me what is the correct way to do this. I have found some articles on the internet, but the more I read the more I get confused.

Thanks
Vandana

Comment: Eclipse has an import function. File > import > import existing Java project

Answer (score 1):

You should have probably chosen to Import Existing Project into your workspace and you should try that instead. It works great as long as you have your .project file defined. To fix the errors you have now, Create a new src folder in your project and point it at trunk\src, so that it correctly recognizes all your Java files.

Comment: I tried doing that, but the problem is the package appears as java.xyz

Comment: rather than package xyz (to which my source files belong) !!. So I have errors shown up in my source files.

Comment: Ah, so you have a Java folder under trunk\src. Then define your src folder in Eclipse as trunk\src\java, and your good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use `myfolder\trunk` as the root of your project, rather than `myfolder\trunk\src`. As **Perception** has mentioned, try to "Import Existing Project" first (rather than start a new project and point it at your source).

Answer (score 0):

First, I assume you already have subversive/subclipse plugin installed in your Eclipse and you have used the right URL to import your source code.

Before checkout your source code, you may change your perspective to Java perspective.

Then you only need to use File-Import-SVN(choose SVN as your import source)-Checkout projects from SVN-Next-Give your project a Name-Finish.

If you have problem about installing SVN plugin, reference is http://subclipse.tigris.org/
http://www.eclipse.org/epsilon/doc/articles/epsilon-source-svn/